# Is there a way to import multiple roles using a single role schema on terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-import

I am new to terraform, and we wanted to migrate our AWS account, we decided to use terraform.I wanted to import all roles in IAM.Currently, I am able to import only single role at once.Is there a way to import all iam_roles at once?

Comment: I would honestly recommend to not import all of them into a single resource as in the future you're going to have to make changes to the resource (the IAM role) anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Using Terraform itself you can only import **by one** IAM resources. But there is a tool to import services to code "**[Terraformer: Infrastructure to code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer)**".

**Here is tutorial how to use it:**
https://betterprogramming.pub/terraformer-converting-infrastructure-into-reusable-terraform-code-afe543ad0b15

Using this tools you can import all iam resources using command:

```
terraformer import aws --resources=iam
```